# OpenApi not picking up 'example' from @Schema

Tags: spring-boot, openapi

In my request model, I have a field like

```
    @NotNull
    @Schema(description = "blahblah", example = "19680228", type = "Date", format = "String", pattern = "([0-9]{4})(?:[0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})", required = true, nullable = false)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
    private OffsetDateTime birthDate;
```

As you can see, I have `example = "19680228"` in `@Schema`.

When I go to https://editor.swagger.io/ and paste my .yaml file into it, I would expect that it would pick the `example` up and show the `birthDate` in example section of my endpoint and in my model schema as 19680228.  I would else expect that `example` was generated in yaml when I hit the /api-docs.yaml endpoint but it is not:
[image]

Here is how it shows in my model:
[image]

And here is how Example value of my controller looks:
[image]

As you can see, the format is still getting the format for `OffsetDateTime` and there is no `example` at all.

However, if I modify yaml in https://editor.swagger.io/ and add example as below:
[image]

, then my schema model shows it
[image]

, and also example in controller shows it as 19680210:
[image]

So, it looks like OpenApi is not processing `@Schema` properly.

Comment: There is probably mismatch between type (should be string) and format (should be date), see https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/ .

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, and i didn't find proper solution for it, the only solution was using String type with pattern.

like this
`@Schema(type = "String" , example = "2022-10-10 00:00:00", pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`.

Comment: Thanks, I know about that but the problem is that the OpenApi let's you provide examples but it does not pick it up.  Also, not everyone will use that format in example.  For example, in my case, I have no decision in that.  This is definitelly an issue the new with OpenApi